# Save MS Access tables as CSV

Tags: python, csv, ms-access, pyodbc

I am new to Python and request your kind assistance. I have five tables in the MS Access database and I need to compile a CSV file for each of the tables. One of the tables is *Perm_Reviews*, which is part of the snippet. Fortunately, I am able to query the MS Access data and it returns rows and the columns associated from the database. Can someone please provide assistance on how to store the tables as CSV files.

```
import pyodbc
import csv

conn_string = ("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=T:\\DataDump\\7.18.2016 PCR etrakit.accdb")

save_csv = 'C:\Desktop\CSVFiles' 

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)

cursor = conn.cursor()

SQL = 'select * from Perm_Reviews;'

for row in cursor.execute(SQL):
    print row

cursor.close()
conn.close()

print 'All done for now'
```

Comment: Simple solution would be to select all the columns, with an hardcoded comma between them: `SELECT col1, ',', vol2, ',', col3... FROM Perm_Reviews;`. If your columns can contain comma's that will be more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import pyodbc
import csv

conn_string = ("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=T:\\DataDump\\7.18.2016 PCR etrakit.accdb") 

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('select * from Perm_Reviews;')

with open('Perms_Review.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
    writer.writerows(cursor)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module that you can use readily, below a simple example on csv with headers:

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```